# If condition in select query

Tags: postgresql

```
select email from mailing list
```

This is the query i want to use `if` condition. I have a column in mailing list as `unsub`. If this `unsub` is `true` the email should null in the selected result otherwise the email will be the selected result

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
select case unsub when true then null else email end as email,....
from ...
```

see [the docs for more examples](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-conditional.html).

Comment: i try it like this select case contacts.email_unsub when true then NULL else contact_details.email from contacts join contact_details on contacts.id = contact_details.contact_id. It gives error like this  syntax error at or near "from". could you please explain.

Comment: sorry, I forget the "end" keyword. I've added it to my answer (i.e. you need this: "....else contact_details.email end as email from...")

Comment: @Abdul, you forgot `END` after contact_details.email and before from. Do read the fine manual.